# How can I stop an alert in javascript from firing when the page loads, and make it run when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, function, events, alert, timing

Without using jQuery, how can I get a JavaScript alert to fire at the right time? 
It's currently firing when the page loads. 
I created a temp converter and would like the "convert to fahr" button and the "convert to cels" button to fire off the converted temps in a pop up "alert".
Currently both buttons are successfully executing their respective temp conversion math functions but I'd also like to add the alerts when the buttons are clicked.

```
document.getElementById('convert').onclick = makeTempF();
document.getElementById('convertC').onclick = makeTempC();

function makeTempF() {
    var d, b, c;
    var f = document.getElementById('f').value;
    b = f - 32;
    c = b * 5;
    d = parseInt(c / 9);
    alert('Celsius Temperature is ' +d);
    // console.log(d);
}


function makeTempC() {
    var g, b, d;
    var c = document.getElementById('c').value;
    b = c * 9;
    d = b / 5;
    g = parseInt(d +32);
    alert('Fahrenheit Temperature is ' +g);
    // console.log(g);
}
```

Comment: When you use the name of a function and follow it with `()`, that means "call this function now please".

Comment: tip: use `Number(c / 9).toFixed(2)` to get a nicer value instead of `parseInt()`.

Comment: This is a very common mistake (question is probably asked multiple times per day).  There are hundreds of dups.  Something very similar here from only a few hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035493/ajax-content-and-jquery-animation-erfects/23035643#23035643

Answer (score 4):

Assign the callbacks, not what their invocation returns.

```
document.getElementById('convert').onclick = makeTempF;
document.getElementById('convertC').onclick = makeTempC;
```